# using ZEND oauth library without using zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, oauth

I want to use the Oauth for calling the etsy API but I dont have the permission to install php oauth PECL extentsion on the server. So I heard about the ZEND oauth library. Can I use ZEND Oauth library without using the ZENd framework as I have heard that ZEND libraries are loosley coupled and can be used independant of framewrok ? If I can do it. What libraries do I  have to include in my project

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a document once in my Knowledge Base for how to use the library in Zend Framework. See link at the bottom.

In a nutshell you have to provide the base path of the library to the php include path. The important thing here is that you provide the **path for the library and NOT the Zend directory itself**. All files in Zend Framework 1.x have require_once relative to this library path and the Zend folder. (Note that this will be different in ZF2 and it will depend on autoloading). Once you have that in your environment you should be good to access every class in the library and work with it.

```
// define an absolute path to library directory
// Note again: the path is the parent of your Zend folder, not the Zend folder itself.
define('APPLICATION_LIBRARY','path/to/your/library')); 
// now set the include path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
  APPLICATION_LIBRARY, get_include_path(),
)));
```

[Zend Framework as a stand alone library](http://www.adrianworlddesign.com/Knowledge-Base/Zend-Framework/Helpful-Tips/ZF-classes-as-stand-alone-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Install the Zend Framework as usual and just use, what you need.